# Share HTTP port 80 with apache webserver and Node.js REST server

Tags: node.js, apache, webserver, port, restify

In the past, I built a REST API server on WAMP (Windows, Apache server, MySQL, PHP). Recently, I built a REST API server with node.js restify. However, I cannot use port 80 for the node.js REST server because there is a conflict with the Apache server. How can I share port 80 with apache webserver and Node.js REST server?

There was no such problem with the WAMP version. Both REST server and webserver were using HTTP port 80.

Comment: You could also setup a reverse proxy on your apache webserver and e.g. route your node.js port to port 80 on a subdomain like node.domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No port can be shared with 2 listeners. only one application can listen on a port, either apache or node process.

When you say you used it in the past, i am assuming you made 2 web APIs/Apps both hosted from the same apache server. is that correct? If that is correct, then that clarifies earlier you had not two but one web server apache running on port 80, isn't it?

Comment: This is correct. My php code runs the REST server. The PHP code resides on the webserver which listens at port 80.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem , My two applications were running on the same port, so moved one the application to 8080 port , it started working fine . You can go for also by securing one of them , then it will be at different domains according the browser.Specify the IP address , don do it for "localhost"